# Binding Datagrid both ways

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, datagrid

I am trying to data-bind a `List` to a `DataGrid`.

So far it seems to work only one way - when I manually change something entered in the displayed `DataGrid`, the `List` gets updated, but not vice-versa (`DataGrid` does not change when I change something in the `List`).

This is my `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColName" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColProperty" Binding="{Binding MyProperty}" Header="My Property" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I enter my data as follows:

```
Public Class Res
    Public Shared TableData As New List(Of DataItem)
End Class

Public Class DataItem
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property MyProperty() As String
End Class

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim entry As New DataItem
    entry.Name = "Test Name"
    entry.MyProperty = "Test Property"
    Res.TableData.Add(entry)
    Me.MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = Res.TableData
End Sub
```

But then, when I try to change my data, by doing something like:

```
Res.TableData.Item(0).Name = "Changed"
```

it does not work, the value displayed in the `DataGrid` does not change.

Why is this? How can I update my `DataGrid`?

If there is a better way to bind data to `DataGrid`, I am open for suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried using `{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}` and have you implemented the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) on your data class?

Comment: I tried `{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}` and that didn't change anything. Not sure what you mean by latter. Could you please provide some examples?

Comment: How about you just try following the link that I provided for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching, found a solution, that worked.

What I did, I added:

```
Me.MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh()
```

after I changed the value in the `List`.

Thanks.